# Read a file in a jtable

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable, jtextarea

I have a code like this :

```
private void jTable4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {
        System.out.println("clicked");
        int row = jTable4.getSelectedRow();
        if (row != -1) {
            String firstColumnValue = jTable4.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
            String secondColumnValue = jTable4.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
            jTextAreaMainFileHighlight.setText(firstColumnValue); // just show name of a file
            jTextAreaComparingFileHighlighter.setText(secondColumnValue); // just show name of a file

        }
```

You know, the jtabel is contains a name of file. How to read that file to and then show in jTextArea

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic of java file reading .Anyway to read the a file (name given in jtable) and to display the content of the file you can use following

```
    BufferedReader br = null;

            try {

                String str;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(firstColumnValue));

                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                   jTextAreaMainFileHighlight.setText(str);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can also simply use [`JTextComponent.read(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Also you should be using `append()` rather than `setText()`. If you build a String from each line, then to can get the String from the StringBuilder and use `setText()`. Otherwise, with what you are doing, each line will get over-written

Comment: @Krrish Roy , you know. It works, but it just give me a last character of that file. Now, How must I supposed to do