# Failed to read a file in jtable to jTexrArea

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is the update question from this : [Read a file in a jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119034/read-a-file-in-a-jtable) . You know, I have a `jTable` that contains a two name of file that will be read into a `Jtextarea` when it clicked in a row. 
Here is the code :

```
if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {
        int row = jTable4.getSelectedRow();
        if (row != -1) {
            String firstColumnValue = jTable4.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
            String secondColumnValue = jTable4.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
            System.out.println(firstColumnValue + " = " + secondColumnValue);
            BufferedReader brComparedFile = null;

            try {
                String strMainFile;
                String strComparedFile;

                BufferedReader brMainFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(firstColumnValue));
                brComparedFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(secondColumnValue));

                while ((strMainFile = brMainFile.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("File Acuan");
                    jTextAreaMainFileHighlight.read(brMainFile, null);
                }

                while ((strComparedFile = brComparedFile.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("File Pembanding");
                    jTextAreaFileComparedFileHighlighter.read(brComparedFile, null);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (brComparedFile != null) {
                        brComparedFile.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Assumpted, my java project is in folder named final_exam. When the file in `JTable` is located in final_exam folder, it works for read the file into `JtextArea`. But when not in final_exam folder (e.g the name of file is a.java), the exception is :  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: a.java (The system cannot find the file specified)`. 
My goal is : My app is always can read the file wherever that file is located...

[image: This is the screenshot]

Anyone can help ?

```
EDIT
```

this is the code how I create the table :

```
 StringBuilder namaFileUtama = new StringBuilder(); // name of main file
 for (final JCCDFile file : files) {
 JCCDFile temp;
 temp = files[0]; 
 String name = temp.getName();
 String enemy = namaFileUtama.toString();
 DefaultTableModel models = (DefaultTableModel) Main_Menu.jTable4.getModel();
            List<ReportMomentOfTruth> theListRMOT = new ArrayList<ReportMomentOfTruth>();
            ReportMomentOfTruth rmot = new ReportMomentOfTruth();
            rmot.setNameOfMainFile(name);
            rmot.setNameOfComparingFile(enemy);
            theListRMOT.add(rmot);

            for (ReportMomentOfTruth reportMomentOfTruth : theListRMOT) {
                models.addRow(new Object[]{
                    reportMomentOfTruth.getNameOfMainFile(),
                    reportMomentOfTruth.getNameOfComparingFile(),});
            }
```

Comment: 18 questions asked. Not a single answer "accepted". You obviously don't appreciate the help you receive so I will skip this question.

Comment: Please visit [StackOverflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about StackOverflow. how it works?

Answer (score 3):

> "My goal is : My app is always can read the file wherever that file is located"

First of all, it's useless saving only the file name to the table (for this use case)

You instead can save the file to the table as `File` objects, that way you always have the file object to get the path from, no matter where the file is. You can create a custom cell renderer to just render the file name.

Otherwise I don't see how else it's possible to read the file from *"anywhere"*, as you say, just from the file name.

Without seeing how you actually load the file names to the table, I might event suggest maybe using a `JFileChooser`.

Here's an example saving the file as File objects to the table. You need to fill in a couple file names for this example

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class FileRendererDemo {
    private static String filePath1 = " [ Enter a valid file path here ]";
    private static String filePath2 = " [ Enter a valid file path here ]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                File file1 = new File(filePath1);
                File file2 = new File(filePath2);
                String[] cols = {"file 1", "file 2"};
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(cols, 0);
                model.addRow(new File[] {file1, file2});
                model.addRow(new File[] {null, null});
                model.addRow(new File[] {null, null});
                JTable table = getTable(model);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table);
            }
        }); 
    }

    private static JTable getTable(TableModel model) {
        final JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if (row != -1) {
                        System.out.println("file 1 - " + table.getValueAt(row, 0));
                        System.out.println("file 2 - " + table.getValueAt(row, 1));
                    }
                }   
            }
        });
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new FileCellRenderer());
        return table;
    }

    private static class FileCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            JLabel comp = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                    value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            File file = (File)value;
            if (file != null) {
                String fileName = (String)((File)value).getName();
                comp.setText(fileName);
            }
            return comp;
        }
    }
}
```